# Join and group by based on a value of a column to filter

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count

Let's say I have two tables with these data:

```
author
id | name
---------
1  | John
2  | Jack
3  | James
4  | Bob
5  | Gorge

book
id | author_id | title  | state
-------------------------------------
1  | 1         | book_1 | published
2  | 1         | book_2 | pre-published
3  | 1         | book_3 | published
4  | 1         | book_4 | rejected
5  | 2         | book_5 | published
6  | 3         | book_6 | rejected
7  | 3         | book_7 | pre-published
8  | 4         | book_8 | rejected
```

What I want is a sql query that gives me each of author's id and name and number of published book even if they have 0 published. I think it might be an easy query but I stuck in it, what I want is:

```
id | name   | num_of_published_books
------------------------------------
1  | John   |          2
2  | Jack   |          1
3  | James  |          0
4  | Bob    |          0
5  | Gorge  |          0
```

I'm able to fetch first two rows `John` and `Jack`. and also I am able to group them based on `author_id` and `state`. but it was not what I want.

> note that I don't want to use subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  a.id AS author_id,
  a.name,
  COUNT(b.state = 'published' OR NULL) AS num_of_published_books
FROM
  author a
LEFT JOIN
  book b ON a.id = b.author_id
GROUP BY
  a.id, a.name;
```

Hope it will help you.

---

1. `b.state = 'published'`, we can filter out books that have already been published, the result is `false(0)` or `true(1)`.
2. `OR NULL` is to get `NULL` when the result of the previous step is `false(0)`. In my memory, when using `OR` operator to compare non-null value and `NULL` value, the result will always be `NULL`. `COUNT` will `NULL` is ignored.
3. There are two possible results: `true(1) OR NULL` and `false(0) OR NULL`, and their results are `true(1)` and `NULL` respectively.
4. Finally, `Count` counts the number that is not `NULL`.

Comment: Will this really work on Postgresql? (The COUNT looks strange.)

Comment: It is wired for me too, but it works. @jarlh

Comment: Indeed it does. https://dbfiddle.uk/bd4xTzHR

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test it in `Postgresql`, because I don't have it installed, but in `Mysql` it works. @jarlh

Comment: @HuaJFrame Can you explain `COUNT(b.state = 'published' OR NULL)` ? what does it mean? and how it is working?

Comment: Works on Postgresql too, which was unexpected.

Comment: @HuaJFrame Better test and explain code before creating an answer. There are many sites like https://dbfiddle.uk/ that allow to test queries online without installing anything. And an explanation of what your query does will help other people to understand it.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait, it's been a while since I noticed the message, because I'm not very good at English, I use Google Translate, which may affect reading. There are too many words, and there is no markdown format, I will add my personal understanding to the answer.@MehrdadPedramfar

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll keep an eye out, already added the site to my favorites.@JonasMetzler

Comment: You can see a similar usage here. [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/for-absolute-performance-is-sum-faster-or-count/27572#27572)@MehrdadPedramfar

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT author.id, author.name, 
       COALESCE(COUNT(CASE state  
                         WHEN 'published' THEN 1 
                         ELSE O 
                      END), 0)) as num_of_published_books
FROM   author
       LEFT OUTER JOIN book
          ON author.id = book.author_id
GROUP BY author.id, author.name
```

Comment: No need for the COALESCE.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired result, you can use a **LEFT JOIN** and **GROUP BY** in your SQL query.
The LEFT JOIN ensures that all authors from the "author" table are included, even if they have no corresponding records in the "book" table.
Here's the SQL query that should give you the expected result:

```
SELECT a.id,a.name,
  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN b.state = 'published' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS num_of_published_books
FROM author a LEFT JOIN book b ON a.id = b.author_id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name;
```

Check query result http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0db9c8a/1/0

**Explanation:**
The query uses a LEFT JOIN to combine the "author" and "book" tables based on the "author_id." It then employs the SUM function with a CASE statement to count the number of published books for each author (1 for 'published', 0 for others). COALESCE is used to handle NULL values and replace them with 0 in case an author has no published books.

Comment: No need for the COALESCE.

Comment: You are right. we can achieve the same result without using COALESCE since the query will already return 0 when there are no published books for an author due to the LEFT JOIN.
Here's the updated SQL query without the COALESCE function  
`SELECT a.id,a.name,SUM(CASE WHEN b.state = 'published' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_of_published_books
FROM author a
LEFT JOIN book b ON a.id = b.author_id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name;`

Answer (score 0):

One more version using [aggregation with FILTER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES).

```sql
select a.id, min(a.name) as name, 
       count(*) filter (where state = 'published') as num_of_published_books
from author a left outer join book b on a.id = b.author_id
group by a.id;
```

Please note that `min(a.name)` may become simply `a.name` if `author.id` is primary key.
[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/76YYVTWFcxNwxdn7mcR88D/0)